# Deadlocking thread tcp server

Tags: c++, boost

I am using c++ with boost threads, locks mutexs and all that good stuff.

Two threads A and B. A is a networking thread where there is information coming back and forth from the client. B is a worker with variables which needs to be thread safe.

There are multiple threads from the class A and B is just a single thread. Instances of A will be added to B’s list of jobs and A will lock until B has completed the task. (The thread safe list of jobs works fine)

A adds the job to B and then locks, however in most cases before A has locked. B will have processed the job and have (tried to) release the lock before A has applied it. Resulting in As dead lock.

I am not sure what I should be doing here. I could post code but I would imagine is easier to discuss conceptually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is in that the B gets the task and starts to execute it before the thread from A locks. The result you observer can be classified as "missed notification". Quite often when trying to implement two-way synchronization with i.e. mutexes or other simple synchronizers.

You have to make sure that the B does not notify unless A is already waiting, OR you can make sure that the notification is not missed.

While the first way may be a quite tricky to peform , the latter is **very simple**: use a semaphore (or manual-reset-event or (...)).

On semaphores:

- thread A wants to put a job onto queue
- thread A creates a semaphore with COUNT=ZERO and MAX=1
- thread A somehow adds the semaphore to the job
- thread A puts the job on queue
- thread A waits on the semaphore
- thread A destroys the semaphore

while:

- thread B observes the queue
- thread B gets the task
- thread B performs the job
- thread B unlocks the semaphore ONCE

Note that the semaphore UNLOCK is nonblocking if count

Instead of using a semaphore, you can use also events with manual set/reset. Just let the A create-and-lock on the event that is OFF and let the B set it ON.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using locks where you should be using conditions. Quoting [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref):

> The classes `condition_variable` and `condition_variable_any` provide a mechanism for one thread to wait for notification from another thread that a particular condition has become true.

That sounds like what you're trying to do with a lock.